# How does one move forward with an ethereum application?

Tags: dapp-development

Not sure where to post this, but I've gotten into the ethereum programming space and believe that I have developed an interesting product.

I am unsure how I can take this product further, and ask how I can expand/introduce this token to other people, and/or see if people are interested.

So, my question is, once I have an application, where do I go from there. Where could I ask for advice, etc.?

Any help would be largely appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can

- Speak to other people that developed dApps / ICOs / blockchains
- Reach out to potential advisors, people you have identified with skill sets and experience that could add more value to what you have created
- Start bringing others into your project and start to scale it up

Is the goal to launch an ICO or just launch ?

If it is to launch an ICO then you will want to announce it on BitcoinTalk like most other ICOs.  Before doing so you may want to build out the team, build out the advisory board, have a marketing strategy/plan in place and someone to drive it.

If its just to launch it, launch then start getting the word out into different groups and social channels, start to organically build up your community around the product.

I am where you are only myself and my team are ready to do our BitcoinTalk announcement in a few short days.  We spent the last few months building a working beta.  We have had our project, code, whitepaper, vision etc all reviewed by multiple people from different backgrounds technical and non-technical.

From Bitcoin Talk announcement to ICO launch we are looking at 4-6 weeks. Depends on the community interest I guess.  We are giving ourselves at least 4 weeks to drive a marketing campaign to increase awareness of the project/beta & ICO.

Start talking to other people doing the same thing, reach them on twitter, get into the developer chats, into the fb groups, email people directly just start reaching out and asking people.  You will find when you reach out to people they either ignore you completely, happens all the time or they will reply quickly and acknowledge your contact and get back to you at a later date or they will reply with a time when they can spend some time with you.

the only way to get those questions answered is to directly talk with people, don't be afraid of directly contacting someone, don't be worried if someone ignores you just keep plugging away until someone answers.  Start to network both online and offline for peers.

You are welcome to connect

Comment: Hey Lismore, thanks for the great response. My friends and I have been working on this, as well as an extension of the app for a few months now. We are still in school and while we have connections with other people in the tech space, none of them are truly interested in crypto. Would it still be viable to pursue an ico since we do not have too many credentials or would launching app be better?

Comment: the world has changed - young people are side stepping traditional fundraising by adopting the ICO route.  I would not let age hold you back.  For an ICO though you will need to bring on other more experienced people in your team because an ICO with a team of people still in school might not have the credibility or professional history for investors to be assured you will deliver.  If all of you are still in school < meaning high school then perhaps use an adult to connect you with people you think may be able to help.  If all else fails just launch it, look for joint venture partnerships.